# Getting the result of sending an SMS/Email in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project and would like to send SMS and emails and take action depending on whether they were sent, canceled, or failed. I'm currently using [Xam.Plugins.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Messaging/) but I don't see how I'm supposed to get the end status result of this action. With Objective C I would use `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult` to find out if the message was sent or cancelled or failed and with Android's Java I believe there was a BroadcastReceiver that would do the same thing. Does this plugin have that ability and I'm just overlooking it?

If not, then could I implement this myself? I found this other tutorial which shows how to implement cross platform sending of SMS and emails but it also appears to lack a way to get the end result:
http://blog.xamarians.com/Blog/2017/6/28/sending-message-e-mails-and-making-calls

Answer (score 0):

With Xamarin you have full access to the API:s of iOS and Android with C# so you can implement yourself with the same API:s that you should use if you used Objective-C for iOS or Java for Android.

Comment: Yeah, I had read that when I was first looking into using Xamarin Forms. Does this answer mean that you know for sure there's no way to have access to end result of Xam.Plugins.Messaging send action? I would prefer to use a plugin that has been thoroughly tested than writing everything myself. Or at least be able to slightly modify a plugin so that I can have this ability. Seems strange that nobody else using Xamarin Forms needs the result of a send message operation.